# Data table not importing from morningstar

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to take data from https://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=0P0000032S&culture=en&platform=sal and use the values in the table in a Google sheet. This is table1 when I inspect the element but when I use:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=0P0000032S&culture=en&platform=sal","table",1)
```

on google sheets, it says the imported content is empty? Any help on how to import this data?

I've tried `importhtml` using table number references found when I inspected the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, that won't be possible because the site is controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't understand/import JS. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given link and you will see a blank page:

[image: 0]